# Python Dice Game/Loop error

Tags: python

I recently started to make a dice game in python.Everything was nice and beautiful,until now.My problem is that when I try to play and I win or lost or it's equal next time it will continue only with that.

Example:

```
Enter name >> Sorin
Money = 2
Bet >> 2
You won!
Money 4
Bet >> 2
You won!
```

and it loops like this :/

```
Here is the code:

import time
import os
import random
os = os.system
os("clear")

print "What is your name?"
name = raw_input(">>")

def lost():
        print "Yoy lost the game!Wanna Play again?Y/N"
        ch = raw_input(">>")
        if ch == "Y":
                game()
        elif ch == "N":
                exit()



def game():
        os("clear")
        a = random.randint(1,6)
        b = random.randint(1,6)
        c = random.randint(1,6)
        d = random.randint(1,6)
        e = a + b
        f = c + d
        money = 2
        while money > 0:
                print "Welcome to FireDice %s!" %name
                print "Your money: %s$" %money
                print "How much do you bet?"
                bet = input(">>")
                if e > f:
                        print "you won!"
                        money = money + bet
                elif e < f:
                        print "you lost"
                        money = money - bet
                else:
                        print "?"

                print money
        lost()        

game()
```

Comment: You never "re-roll the dice", so to say.  They are evaluated at the start of `game()` and are not part of the loop.

Comment: Also you probably want to add an option to quite while ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Try redefining `game` like this:

```
def game():
    os("clear")
    money = 2
    while money > 0:
            print "Welcome to FireDice %s!" %name
            print "Your money: %s$" %money
            print "How much do you bet?"
            bet = input(">>")
            a = random.randint(1,6)
            b = random.randint(1,6)
            c = random.randint(1,6)
            d = random.randint(1,6)
            e = a + b
            f = c + d
            if e > f:
                    print "you won!"
                    money = money + bet
            elif e < f:
                    print "you lost"
                    money = money - bet
            else:
                    print "?"

            print money
    lost()
```

When you call game, you're giving new values to your random variables in each new iteration.

Comment: I fired out :) anyway thnx for helping!